# Can i set the "ProductName" property at buildtime in a Visual studio Deployment project?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, deployment, setup-deployment

While creating an installation package with a deployment project in VS2008, i would like to read a value from an XML file and set that value as `ProductName` (The Xml file is included in the package).

Is it possible?

Comment: It's unusual that your product name would change each time that you run a build.

Answer (score 0):

.vdproj has internal non msbuild file format. To change ProductName property on the fly you should create custom build script It can be msbuild proj or any other script.

```
productName := ReadValueFromXML(settings.xml, xpathQuery)
CallRegexToReplace(your.vdproj, "ProductName" = "8:DefaultProductNameForRelease", "ProductName" = "8:$(productName)"
devenv.exe /build your.vdproj
```

Product name in project must be as a marker to find and replace it for specified platform/configuration.

You can start from [this](http://thepursuitofalife.com/how-to-build-vdproj-files-in-msbuild/comment-page-1/) and use [MSBuild Community Tasks](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org) namely **RegexReplace** and **XmlRead** to implement it.